# Disable button on a page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following login page

[image: Login Page]

When I click Create Account the Employee Sign in button is shown again.
How do i remove it from this page?
The button is the same and displayed on both pages?
I do not want the button displayed on the Create Account page.

[image: Create Account Page]

here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f17rk9ju/)

```css
$("#form-id").submit(function()
{setTimeout(function(){
alert("Thank you for requesting an  Documentation Center account. Once your request is reviewed by an administrator, you will receive an email with your login credentials."); location.reload();
submit = true;}, 1000);
});
```

```html
<div class="company-logo-container1">
    <a href=(site.uri)><img src=(site.uri & '/@api/deki/files/12133/Acc_Logo_Black_Purple_RGB.png?origin=mt-web' & {default: wiki.cdn('/skins/styles/elm/logo.svg')})/></a>
</div>




<div id="title-container">
    <div class="login-title"> "ALIP CLIENT PORTAL"; <span class="name">"& DOCUMENTATION CENTER"</span></div>
    /*<p id="login-paragraph"> "Supporting our customers by providing documentation for ALIP." </p>*/
</div>

<div id="acc-login-panel">
    <div id="employee-login">
        //<div id="login-subheader">'ALIP Employees'</div>
        //<p class="employee-text">'ALIP Employees: '</p>
        <form id="registerform" method="link" action="https://acclife-prod.mindtouch.us/Special:SAML?returnto=https://acclife-prod.mindtouch.us">
        <button type="submit" name="deki_buttons[action] [login]" value= "Sign In" class="ui-button ui-button-primary" tabindex="3"><span>'Employee Sign In'</span></button>
    
</form>  
    </div>      
  


<div id="customer-header">'Customers and Partners'</div>
        <div id="customer-login">
            <a id="acc-register">
                <input id="showbutton" onclick="
                    //$('#customer-login').hide();
                    $('#mt-login-form').hide();
                    $('#login-subheader').hide();
                    $('#widget-login-panel').hide();
                    $('#acc-password').hide();
                    $('#acc-register').hide();
                    $('#showbutton').hide();
                    $('#accountrequest').show();
                    $('#hidebutton').show();"
                 readonly="true"
                 type="text" 
                 value="Create an Account" />
            </a>
            
            <a id="acc-password">
                <input id="resetbutton" onclick="
                    //$('#customer-login').hide();
                    $('#mt-login-form').hide();
                    $('#login-subheader').hide();
                    $('#widget-login-panel').hide();
                    $('#acc-password').hide();
                    $('#acc-register').hide();
                    $('#showbutton').show();
                    $('#accountrequest').hide();
                    $('#acc-login-panel').hide();
                    $('#employee-login').hide();
                    $('#hidebutton').show();
                    $('#acce-password-panel').show();
                    $('#widget-password-panel').addClass('widget-panel show active-panel');"
                readonly="true"
                type="text" 
                value="Reset Your Password" />
            </a>
        
        <div id="accountrequest" style="">
        <div id="frame-container" >
        <div>template('Custom/LoginForm');</div>
        </div>
              
        <br />
        <input id="hidebutton" onclick="
            $('#customer-login').show();
            $('#mt-login-form').show();
            $('#login-subheader').show();
            $('#widget-login-panel').show();
            $('#acc-password').show();
            $('#acc-register').show();
            $('#showbutton').show();
            $('#accountrequest').hide();
            $('#hidebutton').hide();"

        readonly="true"
        style="display:none; border:none;color:#000;font-size:1.0em;cursor:pointer;"
        type="text" value="Return to Login"/>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
<div id="acc-password-panel">
        <div id="customer-password-header">'Customers and Partners'</div>
        <div id="password-contents">
            <div id="loginReturn"><a href="/Special:Userlogin">'Return to Login'</a></div>
            <div id="contactSC"><a href="mailto:ALIPDocumentationCenter@act.com">'Contact the Documentation Center'</a></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question as is I would say go to the desired page and remove the code you don't need. So I'm sure you could give us some code and explain us where is your problem exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Because you never hide in your `click` attribute of the input.

```
<input id="showbutton" onclick="
    //$('#customer-login').hide();
    $('#mt-login-form').hide();
    $('#login-subheader').hide();
    $('#widget-login-panel').hide();
    $('#acc-password').hide();
    $('#acc-register').hide();
    $('#showbutton').hide();
    $('#accountrequest').show();
    $('#hidebutton').show();"
    readonly="true"
    type="text" 
    value="Create an Account" />
```

By the way, avoid changing the whole page with JavaScript. Don't hide the element, just change page.
In case a user doesn't allow JavaScript or has an old browser version, it could break your logic.

Comment: I think you mixed some stuff. If you want to use button just use `<button>My button</button>` or `<input type="button" value="My button">` why using `readonly="true"` to lookalike button . Also, avoid to hide 8 elements, put them in a single div and hide only one div, or at least use JS function to hide 8 elements. And what I said is to avoid to hide too much element with JS because every user can disable JS or use an old browser and then your logic of hiding/showing will not be right.

Comment: If you really want to keep this logic and this way to handle your case. Add an id to your button and hide it. `<button id="employee-button" type="submit" name="deki_buttons[action] [login]" value= "Sign In" class="ui-button ui-button-primary" tabindex="3"><span>'Employee Sign In'</span></button>` and add `$('#employee-button').hide();` to your `onclick` event

Comment: ...when i do that the Employee Sign in button disappears from the Login page as well....

Comment: ...i resolved it this way $('#acc-login-panel').show(); $('#employee-login').hide(); –...thanks for pointing me in the right direction